# How should I approach programming C++ with the new C++11 standard in place?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've been programming C++ for a little while now and I'm used to doing things like:

```
vector<int> vi;
for (vector<int>::const_iterator it = vi.begin(); it != vi.end(); ++it) {
    // do something with it
}
```

However the new C++ standard, C++11, introduces the `auto` keyword, so I can write things like:

```
vector<int> vi;
for (auto it : vi ) 
    // do something with it
}
```

Should I start using this in my code, or should I use the iterator approach?

The same question goes for many other things in the new C++11 standard. Should I start using the new things in my code and forget about the old ways of doing things?

Comment: It depends.  Are you always going to be using C++11 (or newer)?

Comment: Technically, you want `cbegin` and `cend` for the first. The C++11 stuff is a lot less to read if you're going through the whole container, though, so it saves some good time and space writing. `const` and `&` can be applied to `auto` as needed, as well. It's more like a better version of `std::for_each`.

Comment: It depends an awful lot on the context you're going to be programming in of course. If you're coding for yourself then I'd say go with the new stuff.  It'll be a LONG time before industry (financial at least) gets anywhere near C++11.  I'd say keep yourself fresh on the new stuff.

Comment: @MichaelWilson, I'm going to be so happy when industry starts using it. At this point in time, I'm sure I'd be answering people's questions all day about the various features.

Comment: heh. I'm trying hard to get myself to use "the new stuff" (which is approaching 7-10 years old at this point.) It's just not happening as quick as I'd like.  I'm getting new stuff on interview questions (well, was) and botching it. bad.

Comment: I recomend watching GoingNative 2012 on channel9, especially :

Day 1 Keynote - Bjarne Stroustrup: C++11 Style, 
Day 2 Keynote - Herb Sutter: C++11, VC++11 and Beyond

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the project and compiler support. C++11 adds a lot of things to make your program more readable, faster, more robust, etc.

The only downside to C++11 is that not all platforms support it. Your project requirements may mandate support for platforms or compilers that don't support C++11, or the value gained by moving to C++11 may not as much as what you lose by abandoning compilers or platforms that lack C++11 support.

It's not an all-or-nothing decision. You may be able to pick a few features that work for you and decide to leave some others until later when more of your compilers have better support.

Different projects will be different, and the judgement will depend on how much you value the various benefits brought by C++11 vs. how you value support for older platforms. As time goes on things will swing further in favor of C++11 until there's no question, but for now you just have to look at your projects and decide if, and which parts of, C++11 is acceptable to you.